# $f(x) = (\cos x - \sin x) (17 \cos x -7 \sin x) $

Tags: functions, trigonometry

$f(x) = (\cos x - \sin x) (17 \cos x -7 \sin x)$

Determine the greatest and least values of $\frac{39}{f(x)+14}$ and state a value of x at which greatest values occurs.

Do I just use a graphing calculator for this? Is there a way I could do this without a graphing calculator?

Comment: May be computing the derivative and looking at the solutions of $\Big(\frac{39}{f(x)+14}\Big)'=0$

Answer (score 5):

you can do this without calculus. here is a way.  i will use $t$ for $x.$ we have 
$$\begin{align}y &=  14 + (\cos t - \sin t)(17 \cos t - 7 \sin t) \\&= 14 + 17 \cos^2 t-24 \sin t \cos t+7 \sin ^2 t\\
&=14 + \frac{17}{2}(1 + \cos 2t)-12 \sin 2t+\frac 72(1-\cos 2t)\\
&=26+5\cos 2t-12\sin 2t\\
&=26 + 13\cos(2t+\phi), \text{ where} \cos \phi = \frac 5{13}, \sin \phi = \frac{12}{13} \end{align}$$  so the maximum value of $y$  is $39$ and minimum value of $y$ is $13.$

therefore  $$1 \le \frac {39}{ 14 + (\cos t - \sin t)(17 \cos t - 7 \sin t)} \le 3.$$

Answer (score 1):

**Method#**$1:$

$$f(x)=17\cos^2x+7\sin^2x-24\sin x\cos x=\dfrac{17(1+\cos2x)+7(1-\cos2x)-24\sin2x}2$$

$$=12+5\cos2x-12\sin2x=12+\sqrt{12^2+5^2}\cos\left(2x+\arctan\dfrac{12}5\right)$$

Now for real $x,-1\le\cos\left(2x+\arctan\dfrac{12}5\right)\le1$

**Method#**$2:$
$$f(x)=17\cos^2x+7\sin^2x-24\sin x\cos x$$

Divide both sides by $\cos^2x$ and use $\tan x=t$ to form a quadratic equation in $t$  $$(1+t^2)f(x)=17+7t^2-24t\iff (f(x)-7)t^2+24t+f(x)-17=0$$

Now as $t$ is real, the discriminant must be $\ge0$

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x) = (\cos x - \sin x) (17 \cos x -7 \sin x)\\=17c^2-24sc+7s^2=7+5(1+c_2)-12s_2=12+5c_2-12s_2$$
And as we know $|as+bc|\le\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$, so:
$$-1=12-13\le f(x)\le 12+13=25$$

---

*$s:=\sin,c:=\cos,s_n=s(nx)$